# AWS - Secrets Manager List the Secrets that the User has read access to

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to create a policy such that the user can only list a few secrets. I don't want the user to see any secrets that they don't have access to. How can I achieve this?

So far, by a lot of trial and error, I believe there is no way to restrict the secrets that a user can view (through list secrets).

Apologies if this is a common question but I've tried searching a lot and couldn't find anything concrete.

For example, the following policy will give the use GET & Describe access to all secrets starting with 'key'. The Sid: "SecretsManagerListSecretUserHasAccessTo" part of the policy will allow the user to list all secrets.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SecretsManagerAccess1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:Get*",
                "secretsmanager:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:[region]:[acct-id]:secret:key*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "SecretsManagerListSecretUserHasAccessTo",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:ListSecrets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I try adding some string matching (see example below), then the user is unable to see any secrets (on the console). Error message: "Failed to fetch a list of secrets".

Ideally, the below policy should help the user only list keys that start with k. (OR any other condition also works).

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllResourcesSecretsManagerFullAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:Get*",
                "secretsmanager:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:[region]:[acct-id]:secret:key*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllResourcesSecretsManagerNoTags",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:ListSecrets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:[region]:[acct-id]:secret:k*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: None of the AWS consoles support this use case that I'm aware of. They never issue a qualified List command. They always issue an unqualified List command e.g. ListSecrets, ListBuckets etc. Consequently, if the user policy imposes a restriction then the console cannot list anything.

Comment: Bear in mind that the AWS console may not even be able to determine the IAM policies attached to the console user because it is operating as that user and that user may have zero IAM permissions. So it cannot, in the general case, enumerate the IAM policies in play and hence could not determine what set of secrets it should attempt to list.

Answer (score 0):

This is the policy we use to allow specific accounts access to a set of secrets. In most cases you need to wildcard all `List` and `Get` permissions for things to work in terraform as well.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
        "secretsmanager:List*",
        "secretsmanager:Get*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${aws_region}:${aws_account_id_dev}:secret:dev/var/MY_SECRET",
        "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${aws_region}:${aws_account_id_dev}:secret:dev/var/MY_WILDCARD_SECRETS_*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The above will give the user access to the secret `dev/var/MY_SECRET` and to all secrets starting with `dev/var/MY_WILDCARD_SECRETS_` (i.e. `dev/var/MY_WILDCARD_SECRETS_1`, `dev/var/MY_WILDCARD_SECRETS_WHATEVER`, etc)

You could, of course, fine-tune this to be even more restrictive if you wish. The docs have some good examples to get you going:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access_examples.html#auth-and-access_examples_read